# EC2 in ECS keeps restarting in Aws

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have created an ECS cluster that has created an EC2 instance for me. Since it is in the dev phase, I would like to 'stop' the instance when not in use. But it restarts itself whenever I stop it manually.
I have a faint idea that it might be because of the ASG that tries to maintain it's desired state of 1 instances but how do I control this? If I edit the desired state in ASG to 0, it shuts down my instance altogether.
I just want to stop it when not in use from being unnecessarily billed.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Setting Auto Scaling group's `Desired Capacity` to zero means terminating all of the instances and not stopping them. Setting it to one, one the other hand, means always keeping one instance running. So, it is not possible to have stopped instances in ASG. But you can schedule scaling for your ASG to save some money when you do not use your test machine. Read more about scheduled scaling [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/schedule_time.html).

Comment: Scheduled scaling is not my solution since I do not know traffic trends. The real problem I am facing is the instance restarts whenever I stop it. Since it is in Dev stage, I would like it to not be running all the time.

Comment: ASG adds a new instance because your desired capacity is set to one.

Comment: But shouldn't that be added when the current instance is terminated. How do I stop it from running all the time?

Comment: @Shweta, again, the key is that you cannot have a stopped instance in ASG. It is either running or terminated.